# OpenCV is not initializing

Tags: android, opencv

i want to export bitmaps to video using OpenCV.

OpenCV is initialized in activity:

```
 val openCVIsInitialized = OpenCVLoader.initDebug()
 Timber.d("OpenCV initialized: $openCVIsInitialized")
 if (!openCVIsInitialized) {
     OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, this)
 } else {
     onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS)
 }
```

When i remove `if/else` and only `OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, this)` is run OpenCV init is stuck, in logs i see:

> D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Request new service installation

and `onManagerConnected` is never called.

In

> onManagerConnected

following code is run:

```
when (status) {
    LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS -> {
        Timber.d("OpenCV SUCCESS")
        imageCaptureFragment.setupVideoRecorder()
    }
    LoaderCallbackInterface.INIT_FAILED -> Timber.d("OpenCV INIT_FAILED")
    LoaderCallbackInterface.INSTALL_CANCELED -> Timber.d("OpenCV INSTALL_CANCELED")
    LoaderCallbackInterface.MARKET_ERROR -> Timber.d("OpenCV MARKET_ERROR")
}
```

and then:

```
if (videoWriter?.isOpened == false) {
    val fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G')
    videoWriter = VideoWriter(fileName, fourcc, fps, frameSize)
}
```

While `VideoWriter(fileName, fourcc, fps, frameSize)` is run there is a crash:

> OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: Requested object was not found (could not open directory: /data/app/~~123==/com.test.test-123==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a) in glob_rec, file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/glob.cpp, line 279

Any help? I saw this issue
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18463 but the only one solution/tip does not work for me.